# Light dismissing crashes my app, why?

Tags: windows-runtime

I have a settings flyout and it is working just fine if I dismiss it with a back button, but when i use:

```
IsLightDismissEnabled = true
```

And dismiss the charm by pressing the background form it crashes, and I'm unable to debug.
Has any of you seen this kind of behaviour before?

I will put up the code in question later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:
The `OnWindowActivated` eventhandler was empty which made the app crash on light dismiss